# How to deal with .errors for Django API framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following codes:

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique = True)
    ipaddr = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='ipv4', unique=True, verbose_name='mangement IP') ##Use for mgt_id_addr
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname

class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
    
    SUBNET_CHOICES = (
    ('16','16'),
    ('17', '17'),
    ('18','18'),
    ('19','19'),
    ('20','20'),
    ('21', '21'),
    ('22', '22'),
    ('23', '23'),
    ('24', '24'),
    ('25', '25'),
    ('26', '26'),
    ('27', '27'),
    ('28', '28'),
    ('29', '29'),
    ('30', '30'),
    )

    DEV_MODS =(
        ('Catalyst 9606R', 'Catalyst 9606R'),
        ('C9300L-48T-4X', 'C9300L-48T-4X')
    )

    
    mgt_interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subnetmask = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices = SUBNET_CHOICES)
    ssh_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ssh_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    enable_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dev_mod=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = DEV_MODS) ##device_model replacement
    DD2DKEY = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE) ##The key to link up the tables
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Device, DeviceDetail

class DeviceSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Device
        fields = '__all__'

class DeviceDetailSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceDetail
        fields = ['mgt_interface', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'dev_mod']
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_device(request):
    device = Device()
    devicedetail = DeviceDetail()
    deviceserializer = DeviceSerializers(device, data = request.data)
    devdserializer = DeviceDetailSerializers(devicedetail, data = request.data)
    if deviceserializer.is_valid() and devdserializer.is_valid():   
        device_instance = deviceserializer.save()
        devdserializer.save(DD2DKEY=device_instance)                
        results = {
        "device":deviceserializer.data,
        "device_details" : devdserializer.data,
        }
        return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        errors = {
            "device":deviceserializer.errors,
            "device_details" : devdserializer.errors,
        }
        return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am facing the following error: AssertionError: You must call `.is_valid()` before accessing `.errors`.

How do i correct this to fixed the issue in case my codes enter the else condition so it will show the errors of the serializers? Because no matter what I still have to return a response if it failes

Comment: If `deviceserializer.is_valid()` fails, then it will not call `devdserializer.is_valid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `deviceserializer.is_valid()` fails, then the `if` condition will shortcircuit and thus *not* call `devdserializer.is_valid()`. You thus should ensure that it calls `devdserializer.is_valid()` as well:

```
if deviceserializer.is_valid() and devdserializer.is_valid():   
    device_instance = deviceserializer.save()
    devdserializer.save(DD2DKEY=device_instance)                
    results = {
        "device":deviceserializer.data,
        "device_details" : devdserializer.data,
    }
    return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
    #       ↓ ensure that is_valid() is called
    devdserializer.is_valid()
    errors = {
        "device":deviceserializer.errors,
        "device_details" : devdserializer.errors,
    }
    return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```